# About Selected_int_kind statement

Tags: fortran

After Learning from this website ( http://www.mathcs.emory.edu/~cheung/Courses/561/Syllabus/6-Fortran/kind.html ) about selected_int_kind and selected_real_kind statements in Fortran, I had this question when typing this code:

```
program large_integers

  integer, parameter :: Single = selected_int_kind(precision(1.e0)) 
  integer, parameter :: Double = selected_int_kind(precision(1.d0))
  integer(Single), parameter :: sNaN    = Z"7FC0000"

  integer (single) a
  real(single) b
  integer (double) c
  real(double) d

  write(*,*) 'a = ', a, 'b = ',b , 'c = ' , c, 'd= ', d , sNaN

end program large_integers
```

After running it, it gave me this result :

a =            1 b =   -4.78538941E-39 c =            4294954096 d=    3.1846750471760586E-314   133955584

First of all, precision isn't defined for selected_int_kind but just for selected_real_kind, but here it was.

Second, How could it give a real value for b and d , if single and double are of integer type?

Third, how does it work that sNaN holds a character while it is defined as an integer?

Excuse me if my question seemed silly. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I believe the BOZ constant for `sNAN` should be an argument to `INT()` to be standard conforming.

Answer (score 3):

Let me try to explain and I hope I cover all the questions you raise ...

All Fortran scalars have a `kind` which specifies the range and precision that variables of that kind take.  All the current compilers that I am familiar with, (note that the statements that follow do not necessarily apply to all past or future Fortran compilers) define at least 2 kinds for both real and integer variables.  If you want to think of these kinds as different numbers of bits in the representation of the numbers you won't go far wrong, though the Fortran standard is a bit vague on exactly how numbers are to be represented, leaving much of the detail to the compiler writers and concentrating on the interpretation of programs.

Logical, character and complex variables also come in kinds, but we'll leave those aside for now.

The intrinsic routines `selected_int_kind` and `selected_real_kind` return an integer value expressing the particular compiler's 'code' for an integer (real) of that kind.  Many compilers, though not all, use codes such as `4` and `8` for, respectively, 32- and 64-bit integers (reals) - but do not get hung up on the correspondence, kind 'codes' are arbitrary and at least one current compiler uses `2` and `3` for those instead.  By using the `selected_n_kind` routines your code is platform-independent, you're never using those codes explicitly.

To me it seems odd to use `precision`, with a real argument, as you have done in the calls to `selected_int_kind`, more usually I would expect to have seen integer literal arguments.  A call such as `selected_int_kind(n)` returns the kind code for integers with a range `-10^n .. 10^n`, or -1 if there is no such integer.

As it happens, and you got lucky here, most current compilers use the same kind codes for integers and reals of the same number of bits so you can use `selected_int_kind` to get the codes for both, this is not necessarily true, and a better way to get real kinds would use `selected_real_kind`.

These days you also have recourse to some pre-defined constants.  The intrinsic module `iso_fortran_env` declares constants such as `real32` and `int64` which specify the kind codes and you could just `use` those.  If this leaves you scratching your head a bit, look up some Qs and As here on SO which already cover the matter.

I'm not sure I entirely understand the question implicit in your sentence *First of all ...*.  As I wrote above, most current compilers use the same kind codes for reals and integers.  It's better not to think of integers having precision, all integers are absolutely precise equivalents to 'real' integers, integer variables have limited range.  Real numbers, on the other hand, have precision, most Fortran compilers currently follow IEEE754 for the specification of precision, and range, for reals.

*Second ...* - you've declared `b` and `d` to be of type `real`, of course they have real values.

*Third ...* - `sNan` is an integer by declaration. The term `Z"7FC0000"` is the way Fortran uses hexadecimal digits to set the value of an integer. (You can also use `b` as a prefix for a string of binary digits, `o` for octal.)  I expect, though I didn't check, that `133955584` is the decimal equivalent.

Finally, you have not provided values for any of the variables so the processor interprets whatever bits it finds in memory as a variable of the specified type and writes them out.